# Php substr Utf-8 issue

Tags: php, utf-8, strip-tags

When I run this code

```
   $string='<p>Şelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd</p><p>Şelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd</p><p>Şelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd</p>';

echo substr(strip_tags(trim(html_entity_decode($string,   ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'))), 0, 14);;
```

i get this result.

> Şelamiİnnş�

what is my mistake ?

Comment: your expected output is `pelaminnasd213123wqeqweqwrqasdppelaminnasd213123wqeqweqwrqasdppelaminnasd213123wqeqweqwrqasdp`?

Comment: i get this result if dont substring.  aŞŞŞşşğğüğğii,,qweiiqüweğşşŞelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasdŞelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: `pelaminnasd213123wqeqweqwrqasdppelaminnasd213123wqeqweqwrqasdppelaminnasd213123wqeqweqwrqasdp` is it your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use multi-byte `substr()` function.

Try

```
<?php
$string = '<p>Şelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd</p>p>Şelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd</p><p>Şelamiİnnşşasdüğ213,123wqeq.weqw.rqasd</p>';

echo mb_substr(strip_tags(trim(html_entity_decode($string,   ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'))), 0, 14);;

?>
```

[Ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) | [Demo](https://3v4l.org/9ItsD)

Comment: Call to undefined function mb_substr() i get this error.

Comment: You need to enable `mbstring` PHP extension

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **always** break your problem down into smaller parts to see where it's going wrong:

```
$string=html_entity_decode($string,   ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
echo $string, "\n";
$string = trim($string);
echo $string, "\n";
$string = strip_tags($string);
echo $string, "\n";
$string = substr($string, 0, 14);
echo $string, "\n";
```

If you run that, you'll see that the problem has nothing to do with `strip_tags`, it has to do with `substr`.

The reason is very simple: strings in PHP are just a series of bytes; functions like `substr` don't count "characters" in any meaningful way. So `substr($string, 0, 14)` simply takes the first 14 bytes of the string, which in this case happens to split a "character" which was encoded as more than one byte, using UTF-8.

The most common solution to this is to use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) (part of the "mbstring" PHP extension) which counts "characters" according to some encoding:

```
$string = mb_substr($string, 0, 14, 'UTF-8');
echo $string, "\n"; 
// Şelamiİnnşşasd
```

Note that this will truncate to 14 *Unicode code points*, so can still do odd things like chop an accent off a letter if it's been encoded using a "combining diacritic".

An alternative in some cases would be to use [`grapheme_substr`](http://php.net/grapheme_substr) (part of the "intl" extension) which splits on "graphemes", which are intended to be roughly what people would think of as a "character" or "letter". In this case, it gives the same result:

```
$string = grapheme_substr($string, 0, 14, 'UTF-8');
echo $string, "\n"; 
// Şelamiİnnşşasd
```

But in other cases, it might not:

```
$string = 'noël';
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 3, 'UTF-8'), "\n"; // noe
echo grapheme_substr($string, 0, 3), "\n"; // noë
```